# WiX & DirectX: why am I getting "Invalid command line switch" error from dxsetup.exe?

Tags: wix, directx-9

I am creating a WiX install script that includes DirectX 9 (June 2010) components. Many of my users still use XP. The WiX script defines:

```
<CustomAction Id="Install_DirectX" FileKey="dxsetup.exe" ExeCommand="dxsetup.exe"
Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

<Component Id="dxsetup.exe" Guid="*">
    <File Id="dxsetup.exe" Source="F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Redist\DXSETUP.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
</Component>
```

and executes:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Install_DirectX" After="InstallFiles" >
        NOT REMOVE
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When I run the compiled .MSI, I see a dialog box titled "DirectX" with the error:

> **Invalid command line switch**

Nevertheless the installation completes normally: the program is installed and runs. Perhaps DirectX was already present on the target system.

Note that when I use this:

```
ExeCommand="dxsetup.exe /silent"
```

I get the same error message, but the installation fails and rolls back. The log file says:

```
Action 19:29:27: Install_DirectX. 
Action start 19:29:27: Install_DirectX.
Install_DirectX: 
Action ended 19:29:27: Install_DirectX. Return value 1.
(...)
Action 19:29:29: Install_DirectX. 
CustomAction Install_DirectX returned actual error code -9 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
(...)
Action 19:29:39: LaunchApplication. 
Action start 19:29:39: LaunchApplication.
Action ended 19:29:39: LaunchApplication. Return value 3.
DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action LaunchApplication failed.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2896. The arguments are: LaunchApplication, , 
Action ended 19:29:39: ExitDialog. Return value 3.
Action ended 19:29:39: INSTALL. Return value 1.
=== Logging stopped: 01-Dec-2014  19:29:39 ===
MSI (c) (A8:D4) [19:29:39:581]: Product: 3D Family Tree -- Installation completed successfully.
```

This happens before I even get prompted to launch the app. Besides, it only fails when I say `ExeCommand="dxsetup.exe /silent"`, it does not apppear when `ExeCommand="dxsetup.exe"`.

When DXSETUP is not invoked at all (commented out), the installation does not display an error message.

Orca shows this in the "Custom Action" section:

```
Action            Type   Source        Target
Install_DirectX   3154   dxsetup.exe   dxsetup.exe
```

In my old InstallShield script, when the command "dxsetup.exe /silent" was launched, it ran fine and did not display an error.

The installer is available here if you're curious (16MB):
http://www.findyourfamilytree.com/exe/3DFT1.msi

I'm developing and installing on Windows 7, using WiX 3.7.

So, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExeCommand` should be the arguments that are passed to `dxdiag.exe`, not the actual command line, including `dxdiag.exe`.

What about this:

```
<CustomAction Id="Install_DirectX" FileKey="dxsetup.exe" ExeCommand="/silent"
Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />
```

ps, if it helped, don't be afraid to leave me positive feedback in odesk :-)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I was confused because this type of thing `ExeCommand='Install.exe "PDF Printer" -s -n "ABC"'` worked successfully for a different app. You'll get better than feedback at oDesk  :o)